# Why is my Enitty.Contains(attributeField) returning false when I am able to set the value?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a block of code that is not working as I thought it would.

I have set an Entity up as follows and have a previous guid.

```
parentEnt = new Entity("vehicle_ent");
parentEnt.id = guid;
```

Now when I do a check with a statement:

```
if (parentEnt.Contains("attribute_field")) {
    parentEnt["attribute_field"] = "test";
}
```

The above will never be called because the if statement fails.

However, if I remove the if statement. I am able to actually assign and run the code:

```
parentEnt["attribute_field"] = "test";
```

Is there something I am missing with the Contains Method? I thought it was used to check if the Entity contains the attribute?

Comment: It checks if the entity contains a value for the attribute.  Not if it is a valid attribute for the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the constructor for a CRM entity object, and assign it a guid
Like

```
Entity parentEnt = new Entity("vehicle_ent");
parentEnt.id = guid;
```

you are creating a new object of the entity type with the 'vehicle_ent' logical name and a id of 'guid' At this point all the attribute/properties that belong to an entity with that name, are not created along with the entity object, and you only have an Entity class object with a LogicalName and id set.

If you want to check if an entity record with that id contains a certain attribute, you need to fetch is from the database, using your the organization service, like

```
ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(true);
parentEnt = _service.Retrieve("vehicle_ent", guid, attributes);
```

After the retrieve is called you can check if the entity record contains the attribute you need to check.

Comment: Be aware that the solution you propose requires a call to the crm, in this case if he knows the id, and the name of the property he will be able to update the entity simply by adding the missing property that is not present in the list.

Comment: I am not sure, what is there to be aware about, but yes there is a call to the crm. How else would you check if an entity record with a certain guid contains an attribute?

From the example shown and the question asked it is clear that the entity object doesn't contain the  attribute before the check. In my answer i presume that it is expected an attribute to be contained in the entity object during creation, which  seems to be the issue in this case.

Comment: For reference, even when you make a call to the crm, using all new ColumnSet(true) as column set, you still need to check if the returned entity contains the attribute, as it may not contain it for various difference reasons like field security or the field of the record doesn't contain a value.

Comment: This is not at all answering the OP question.  @BlueSam actually answers that.

Answer (score 2):

On the Entity class, you can always assign an attribute like the example you provided whether or not it exists. If it exists, it will overwrite it (which is what you discovered).

So

```
parentEnt["attribute_field"] = "test";
```

Will always work, whether or not the attribute already has a value assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I just add a couple of things:

The syntax `entity[attributename]` and `entity.Attributes[attributename]` are equivalent, the reason can be found inside the Entity metadata:

```
public object this[string attributeName] { get; set; }
```

the method maps at entity level the `Attributes` property (the type of this property is `AttributeCollection` an inherit from `DataCollection<string,object>` and the base type is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`)

`DataCollection` contains this method:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the value associated with the specified key.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   key:
    //     Type: TKey. The key of the value to get or set.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     Type: TValue The value associated with the specified key.
    public virtual TValue this[TKey key] { get; set; }
```

this method adds the key (our attributename) inside the collection if the key is not present before. For this you can assign a value to an attribute without using the `Contains` method first. Of course when you read the value you need to check if the key is present, this is the purpose of the `Contains` method, but to read the values the `GetAttributeValue` can be used as well (but it's necessary to pay attention to the default values returned when the attribute is not inside the collection)